# O que !cin significa em c++?

Tags: c++

Código:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Por favor, insira uma expressao (podemos processar +, -, * e /): " << endl;
    cout << "acrescente um x para terminar a expressao (p.ex., 1+2*3x): " << endl;
    int lval = 0;
    int rval;
    char op;
    cin >> lval; // ler operando esquerdo
>>  if (!cin)
        printf("falta primeiro operando");
    while (cin >> op)
    { // ler repetidamente o operador e operando direito
        if (op != 'x')
            cin >> rval;
        if (!cin)
            printf("falta segundo operando");
        switch (op)
        {
        case '+':
            lval += rval; // somar: lval = lval + rval
            break;
        case '-':
            lval -= rval; // subtrair: lval = lval – rval
            break;
        case '*':
            lval *= rval; // multiplicar: lval = lval * rval
            break;
        case '/':
            lval /= rval; // dividir: lval = lval / rval
            break;
        default: // mais nenhum operando: imprimir resultado
            cout << "Resultado: " << lval << '\n';
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("expressão incorreta");
}
```

O que ele verifica fazendo isso ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao escrever `!cin`, você está implicitamente tentando converter cin, que é do tipo `basic_istream` em um tipo `bool`. Isso funciona pois basic_istream define em algum lugar da sua cadeia hierárquica uma sobrecarga de operador para este tipo de conversão.

O comportamento da conversão de cin em específico está definida aqui: https://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

> "true se o fluxo não tem erros, caso contrário false."

Para ser mais especifico, uma `basic_istream` será convertida para true somente se `basic_istream.fail()` e `basic_istream.bad()` forem falsos. E diferentemente de `basic_istream.good()`, a conversão para bool ainda resulta em `true` mesmo se o fim do stream `eof` já tiver sido alcançado.

Aqui é possível ver o que pode causar o bit de `fail` e `bad` a serem acionados (em inglês):
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate

Por exemplo, se no seu código `cin >> lval` falhasse por motivo do usuário entrar com um valor que não pode ser convertido no tipo de `lval`, o `fail` bit seria acionado e a conversão para `bool` que segue retornaria `false`.

Exemplo de sobrecarga para bool:

```
#include <iostream>

// Classe de exemplo para demonstar a capacidade de sobrecarregar conversões
class GuardaNumero
{
    int m_meuNumero;

public:
    GuardaNumero(int numero)
    {
        this->m_meuNumero = numero;
    }

    // Esta função está sobrecarregando a conversão para bool, sempre que GuardaNumero sofrer
    // conversão para bool, esta função determinará o valor desta booleanica.
    operator bool()
    {
        // true caso meuNumero seja maior que 25, falso caso contrário.
        return this->m_meuNumero > 25;
    }

};

int main()
{
    GuardaNumero a(10); // Menor que 25
    GuardaNumero b(24); // Menor que 25
    GuardaNumero c(26); // Maior que 25
    
    // Conversão implícita para bool de a
    if (a)
        std::cout << "O numero de a e maior que 25" "\n";

    // Conversão explícita para bool, mesmo processo da implícita de b
    if (static_cast<bool>(b))
        std::cout << "O numero de b e maior que 25" "\n";
    
    // Conversão implícita para bool de c
    if (c)
        std::cout << "O numero de c e maior que 25" "\n";

    // Conversão explícita para bool, mesmo processo da implícita de c
    if (static_cast<bool>(c))
        std::cout << "O numero de c ainda e maior que 25" "\n";

}
```

Output:

```
O numero de c e maior que 25
O numero de c ainda e maior que 25
```

A sobrecarga de bool normalmente serve para trazer informações relacionadas ao estado do objeto.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Editei a resposta para ser mais específica em relação aos erros de cin em geral.